How to get back only the inserted rows when using Sequelize's bulkcreate
I'm using Sequelize's bulkcreate to insert multiple users at once. On the users table there is a unique constraint on the email column. To make sure the function continues to run if a second user would be created with the same email I added the ignoreDuplicates: true option.
const createdUsers = await users.bulkCreate(usersArr, {
    ignoreDuplicates: true,
});

My expectation of createdUsers is an array with only the newly inserted users. Unfortunately I get all rows back, including the ignored ones.
Is there a way to only get the newly inserted records back?
